# Using two Flatlists in a Scrollview to create a bildirectional loading effect

Tags: react-native

I am trying to figure out how to create a bidirectional loading flatlist. Right now if you add data to the top of a flatlist, it will renreder and repositiin to the top of the flatlist.

I know there is a way some users have rigged up to perform an animated scroll. But that still creates kinda a choppy effect.

My thinking was if i had two flatlists, one of which serves as my new data, I could house those in a scrollview, and essentially get the scrollview to act like a window, And have its position not be affected by any of the rendering

Does anyone have a solution for any of this? I saw one of the RCs just added this to ios, but I am trying tonget it working on Android as well :(

Comment: So you want two scrollviews (FlatLists) inside a scrollview? Can you give a video example of what you're talking about? I'm having a hard time trying to understand the behavior you want

Comment: Yeah probably vague, have you seen twitters app? He loads in bi direction

Comment: So for example pull refresh at the top and when you're at the bottom load older content? Sounds like one `FlatList` to me. As for adding to the top of the list, I'd suggest not actually adding to the list, but instead show UI indicating that there's new content if you poll for content and there's new stuff. Then when they tap that UI, scroll to the top and show the new content. There's probably a way to add to the list without causing a scroll to the top, but that's one idea to work around it.

Comment: I believe he's talking about a behavior like Facebook Messenger, which loads older content when scrolled to the top and adds new content at the bottom. Also, the scroll position is not affected in both the situations.